# go not in vscode workspace settings user settings

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have installed `Go` Extension in VSCode, and in `How to use this extension?` section on [Extension Web Page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukehoban.Go), it mentions many go settings like `go.toolsGopath`, `go.gocodeAutoBuild`, `go.formatOnSave`,

But when I use <kbd>Ctrl + ,</kbd> to [Open the User Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings), I **didn't** see any `Go` settings, there's no `Go` Settings block in User Settings:

[image]

How do I make `Go` Settings show in User Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, by setting the `Go Extension` to `Enable (Always)`, then `Go Settings (Go configuration)` will show in the user settings.

Step:

1. Open the Extension Tab (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+X</kbd>) in VS Code, and Search "Go".
2. Click the gear and set `Enable (Always)`
3. Click Reload, and `Go configuration` will appear in user settings.

---

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

[image]